# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire, optional-parameters

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Im just trying to receive signals from thing speak.

```
   `self.title = "Home"
    print("Requesting data...")
    Alamofire.request( "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/290427/feeds.json", parameters: ["results": "1", "location": "false"]) // Gets the latest info from ThingSpeak
        .responseJSON { response in

            print("Data downloaded: \(response.result)")
            if let json = response.result.value as! [String:Any] {
                print(json) //see full data

                if let feeds = json["feeds"] as? [String: Any] {

                    for feed in feeds {
                        print(feed["field2"])
                        if let temperatureStr = feed["field2"] as? String, let dateStr = feed["created_at"] as? String {
                            if let temperature = Double(temperatureStr){
                                self.label.text = "Temperature: \(temperature)°F" //Displays last updated data entry

                            }
```

The error is in the line

```
if let json = response.result.value as! [String:Any] {
```

Error message says "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'

Comment: Replace `as!` by `as?`  (as you do it 2 lines below). – Btw, your question title does not even match the error message.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna use conditional binding, the right side of the expression should be optional.

Change this:

```
if let json = response.result.value as! [String:Any]
```

To this:

```
if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any]
```

Comment: These don't work. Gives me several build errors further down.

Comment: [Heres the build errors I have when I put in the ?][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKnua.png

Comment: @ColinH The answer is correct. Those new errors have nothing to do with the original question. There are a bunch of syntax errors in your code (e.g. it's `DateFormatter()` and not `DateFormatter`) and you should just fix them.

Comment: @ColinH What I answer is for the conditional binding. From your screenshot, it seems you have many other issues on your code side which you didn't ask for it from your question.

Answer (score 1):

That message mean that you need to have optional type so just change

`if let json = response.result.value as! [String:Any] {`
to

```
if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
```